TextField Inside ExposedDropdownMenu doesn't show software keyboard
I have a ExposedDropdownMenu and the first Menu item is a OutlinedTextField that filters the menu items. It's work fine in VM and physical keyboard but it doesn't show software keyboard on VM and physical device. Here is the code:
ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = isExpanded,
        onExpandedChange = {
            isExpanded = !isExpanded
        },
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = {

            },
            readOnly = true,
            trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = isExpanded) },
            modifier = modifier.menuAnchor(),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors().copy(
                focusedContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedContainerColor = Color.Transparent
            ),
            label = label,
            isError = isError,
            supportingText = supportingText

        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = isExpanded,
            onDismissRequest = { isExpanded = false }

        ) {
            if (isSearchEnabled) {
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = searchQuery,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 8.dp),
                    onValueChange = {
                        searchQuery = it
                        onSearch(it)
                    },
                    trailingIcon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Search,
                            contentDescription = ""
                        )
                    },

                    label = { Text(text = "Search") },

                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors().copy(
                        focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
                        unfocusedContainerColor = Color.White
                    )
                )
            }

            values?.forEach {
                DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text(text = it.first) }, onClick = {
                    onOptionSelected(it.first, it.second)
                    isExpanded = false
                },
                    contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding
                )
            }
        }
    }

it gets the focus but only flicking courser and  not showing keyboard.
appreciate for any help

After some experiments, I found that replacing ExposedDropdownMenu with DropdownMenu resolves the issue.

You have readOnly = true, which prohibits changing the text and therefore the keyboard is not shown

It's not about that textfield. The textfield in the ExposedDropdown Menu is the problem and also geting readonly=false doesn't have any effect
